# Overloaded operator returning type

Tags: c++, oop

Is it possible to overload an operator returning a string instead of a class type?

```
string operator++() {
    index++;
    if (index > num_atts) {
        index = 0;
    }

    string ret = att_names[index];
    return ret;

}
```

Comment: You have [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). Return a `std::string`.

Comment: You can return any type you like.  However, your above code exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why would you think that was not possible anyway? You can return whatever you want. Also heed @chris's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return any type you like, just like any other function you write.  But just like any other function, you can't return a pointer to a local stack variable that's about to go out of scope, that's undefined behaviour.  The easiest thing to fix that is to simply return the `string`, something like:

```
std::string operator++() {
    // ...
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks, corrected that right after my posting the question :)

Answer (score 1):

That code has no error on syntax. However, it have crucial error on semantic.

```
const char *operator++() {
    index++;
    if (index > num_atts) {
        index = 0;
    }

    string ret = att_names[index]; // 1
    return ret.c_str();            // 2 & 3
}                                  // 4
```

1. The `ret` object is created
2. You call `ret.c_str()`. `ret` object make the c-string for you, and return it.
3. Now, you're trying to return the c-string.
4. But at this time, `ret` is destroyed, and it also destroy c-string, because the owner of that c-string is `ret`.
5. Therefore, now you're returning the *destroyed* pointer!!